# Codeigniter, Search yields different results

Tags: codeigniter, where-in

**How can i have my search result be like this:**

1. category(CAT) is the main query, when category(CAT) is present it will only have result shown in categories(CAT) with different locations(INTL, DOM), (current code does not do that).
2. same with salary(SAL)

   ```
   public function seeker($limit='', $start='')
   {   
   if($this->input->get('DOM', FALSE)){
       $ukcountry = $this->input->get('DOM', TRUE);
       $expukcountry = explode(',', $ukcountry);

       if($this->input->get('INTL', FALSE)){
        $this->db->or_where_in('m_region.regionID', $expukcountry);
        }
        else $this->db->where_in('m_region.regionID', $expukcountry);
   }
   if($this->input->get('INTL', FALSE)){
       $intlcountry = $this->input->get('INTL', TRUE);
       $expintlcountry = explode(',', $intlcountry);

       if($this->input->get('DOM', FALSE)){
           $this->db->or_where_in('m_country.code', $expintlcountry);
       }
       else $this->db->where_in('m_country.code', $expintlcountry);
   }
   if($this->input->get('SAL', FALSE)){
       $salary = $this->input->get('SAL', TRUE);
       $expsalary = explode(',', $salary);
       $this->db->where_in('job_salary.code', $expsalary);
   }
   if($this->input->get('CAT', FALSE)){
       $category = $this->input->get('CAT', TRUE);
       $expcategory = explode(',', $category);

       if($this->input->get('INTL', FALSE) && $this->input->get('DOM', FALSE)){
           $this->db->where_in('job_category_group.categoryID', $expcategory);
       }
       else $this->db->or_where_in('job_category_group.categoryID', $expcategory);
   }

   if($this->input->get()){
       $this->db->join('job_category_group', 'emp_jobs.id = job_category_group.postID', 'left');
       $this->db->join('job_category', 'job_category_group.categoryID = job_category.code', 'left');
       $this->db->join('emp_account', 'emp_jobs.employer_id = emp_account.id', 'left');
       $this->db->join('m_region', 'emp_jobs.region_id = m_region.id', 'left');
       $this->db->join('m_country', 'emp_jobs.location_id = m_country.id', 'left');
       $this->db->join('job_salary', 'emp_jobs.salary_id = job_salary.id', 'left');
       $this->db->select('job_category.category');
       $this->db->select('job_category_group.postID, job_category_group.categoryID');
       $this->db->select('emp_account.company as employerName');
       $this->db->select('m_region.name as regionName');
       $this->db->select('m_country.name as countryName');
       $this->db->select('job_salary.range as salary');
       $this->db->select('emp_jobs.title as jobposition');
       $this->db->select('emp_jobs.start_date as postdate');
       $this->db->where('emp_jobs.status', 'active');
       $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
       $this->db->group_by('emp_jobs.id');
       $this->db->order_by('emp_jobs.start_date', 'desc');
       $query = $this->db->get('emp_jobs');

       return $query->result_array();
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Unclear what you actually need ....

Comment: i rephrased my title, hope that helps.